# How can I get api/register with Passport in laravel working?

Tags: laravel, postman, laravel-passport

Following a tutorial: https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-secure-api-php-laravel-passport
I manAged to get Laravel/Passport installed formy Laravel Api and Vue application.

I managed to create attoken with:

```
localhost:8000/oauth/token
```

get the login working in Postman:

```
localhost:8000/api/login?email=jennie05@example.com&password=password
```

Now when I try to register a user I get returned to the home-page.

I do get some "undefined method" errors from VS Code, but they show up in the login method,
and not in the failinf register method:

Here is the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:55',
            'email' => 'email|required|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed'
        ]);
        

        $validatedData['password'] = bcrypt($request->password);

        $user = User::create($validatedData);

        $accessToken = $user->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;

        return response([ 'user' => $user, 'access_token' => $accessToken]);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $loginData = $request->validate([
            'email' => 'email|required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if (!auth()->attempt($loginData)) {
            return response(['message' => 'Invalid Credentials']);
        }

        $accessToken = auth()->user()->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;

        return response(['user' => auth()->user(), 'access_token' => $accessToken]);

    }
}
```

In these are the routes in api.php:

```
Route::post( 'register', 'App\Http\Controllers\API\AuthController@register');
Route::post( 'login', 'App\Http\Controllers\API\AuthController@login');


//  Route::prefix('v2')->group(function(){   // prefix voor versie 2
    Route::apiResource('/cards', 'App\Http\Controllers\CardController');

    Route::apiResource('/games', 'App\Http\Controllers\GameController');

    //Route::get('games', 'App\Http\Controllers\GameController@index')->middleware('auth:api');
    //Route::post('games', 'App\Http\Controllers\GameController@store')->middleware('auth:api');
    //Route::get('games/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\GameController@show')->middleware('auth:api');
    //Route::put('games/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\GameController@update')->middleware('auth:api');
    //Route::delete('games/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\GameController@destroy')->middleware('auth:api');

    Route::get('/gameByPin/{pin}', 'App\Http\Controllers\GameController@searchPin');

    Route::apiResource('/speler', 'App\Http\Controllers\SpelerController');
//});


Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

is there anyone who can help troubleshooting this?

Postman does not give me errors, just the redirect to homepage..

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your laravel.log? And your headers while making the request does it accept application/json?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. 
No errors in laravel log.
Added accept  application/json, but only see the request info: array:3 [
  "name" => "jennis"
  "email" => "snip@snap.nl"
  "password" => "password"
] after I entered this as FormData with additional  "password_confirmation = password

Maybe I am just doing stuff wrong in postman?

The records are also not added to the database user-table

Comment: So in your api call try and add the following header. 'Accept': 'application/json'

Comment: did do that, using the headers tab in PostMan
Now the array with name, email and password is returned.
A pity that I cannot send the screengrab..

I would expect a token to be returned...

Comment: So your response is returning your user but not the access token? Did you add hasApiTokens to your User model?

Comment: Yes, I did. VS code shows error about it, but I do not understand why... also added use laravel/passport/passport. Also does not create the user...

Comment: Okay so what error is vscode giving? And did you add Passport::routes() to your AppServiceProvider? You are probably just missing a step. You can check passport documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#introduction

Comment: Thnx. Get back after dinner..

Comment: Alrighty then. You are most welcome

Answer (score 0):

Wow,
Thanks Patrick, your the best.

Just checked all the steps in the documentation.

reran the installation command I ran when setting up everything. ( Apperently need to do this twice ?!):

```
php artisan passport:install
```

It returned:

```
Encryption keys already exist. Use the --force option to overwrite them.
Personal access client created successfully.
Client ID: 5
Client secret: ikJEfthxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxBjJ36
Password grant client created successfully.
Client ID: 6
Client secret: H42lpMxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxQGZgH
```

Now the post request results in a token!

The error VS Code shows d for "use HasApiToken" is:

```
Undefined type 'Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens'.intelephense(1009)
```